# "WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8000/ws/chat/cujncvifd/' failed"

Tags: javascript, python, django, websocket, django-channels

I am getting a "WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8000/ws/chat/cujncvifd/' failed" error in my django application. I am also getting a "Not Found: /ws/chat/cujncvifd/" statement in the terminal. The following are the relevant pieces of code from the mentioned files:
settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'channels',
    'common_anime_chat.apps.CommonAnimeChatConfig',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    
]

ASGI_APPLICATION = 'anime_chat_app.routing.application'
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default':{
        "BACKEND":"channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer"
    }
}
```

asgi.py:

```
import os
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
import common_anime_chat.routing


os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'anime_chat_app.settings')

#the new code about the application you told me to write
```

routing.py (main project directory):

```
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator
import common_anime_chat.routing

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'websocket':AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            common_anime_chat.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
    "http":get_asgi_application(),
   
})
```

routings.py (from common_anime_chat which is an app):

```
from django.urls import re_path
from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^ws/chat/(?P<room_name>\w+)/$', consumers.ChatRoomConsumer.as_asgi())
]
```

consumers.py:

```
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
import json

class ChatRoomConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        await self.accept()

        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type':'tester_message',
                'tester':'hello world'
            }
        )

    async def tester_message(self, event):
            tester = event['tester']
            await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
                 'tester':tester,
            }))
    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
```

common_anime_chat/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='common-anime-chat-home'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='common-anime-chat-about'),
    path('chat/<str:room_name>/', views.room, name='room'),
]
```

chatroom.html:

```
{% extends 'common_anime_chat/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block stylesheet %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'chatroom.css' %}">
{% endblock stylesheet %}
{% block content %}
<div id="user-hello"></div>

{{ room_name|json_script:"room-name" }}
<script>
    const roomName = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('room-name').textContent);
    console.log(roomName)
    const chatSocket = new WebSocket(
        'ws://' +
        window.location.host +
        '/ws/chat/'+
        roomName +
        '/'
    );

    chatSocket.onmessage = function (e) {
        const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
        document.querySelector('#user-hello').innerHTML = (data.tester);
    };
</script>
{% endblock content %}
```

I have tried interchanging between "ws://" and "ws/" in routings.py from the common_anime_chat app but that was to no avail

I also tried removing the "ws" from the JS websocket connection in the template when forming the websocket link but that did not seem to work either

the roomName variable is returing a valid value as I have verified that from the console.

I have tried turning my firewall off but that did not help either.

I have also restarted the server and my django and channels versions are up to date.

I am following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F4nwRQPXD8w&t=4166s

I am new to websockets so I don't have much clue of what I am doing so please help me out!

Comment: Are you working locally ? If yes try to run `python manage.py runserver` to see if you ASGI is working.

Comment: @ThiernoAmadouSow thanks for your help! I managed to fix it but I have a different error now. I have tried my best to solve it but I am not able to do so. I have created a different post so please check it out.